# Passing different instances of same Model to same SwiftUI View struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Tab-based app, implemented in Swift, and using SwiftUI.

For 2 of the tabs, I want to show Lists based on the same SwiftUI struct, displaying different instances of the same class.

In the SceneDelegate,

```
    let naughtyModel = SantaListModel(title: "Naughty")
    let niceModel    = SantaListModel(title: "Nice")

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()
        .environmentObject(naughtyModel)
        .environmentObject(niceModel)

    ...
```

Then,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    @EnvironmentObject var naughtyModel: SantaList
    @EnvironmentObject var niceModel: SantaList

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            SantaListView().environmentObject(naughtyModel)
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Text(naughtyModel.title)
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            SantaListView().environmentObject(niceModel)
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Text(niceModel.title)
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
            }
        }
   }
```

All apparently good so far, but when I implement SantaListView, a shared struct implementation to display the different instances, the plan goes awry...

```
struct SantaListView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var santaListModel: SantaList // <<< the problem: naughty or nice?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
            }
           .navigationBarTitle(Text(santaListModel.title))
        }
    }
}
```

In SantaList class implementation, how do I refer to the specific @EnvironmentVariable, such that santaListModel above refers to the specific instance naughtyModel or niceModel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very clear why... but that's different question. _How_ modelA differs from modelB? If you need to do something conditionally in `MyModelView` then put that condition into constructor parameter.

Comment: They are two instances of the same model, holding different lists of data, let's say Santa's naughty list, and Santa's nice list ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to simply create two subclasses for the model:

```swift
class NaughtyList: SantaListModel {
  init() {
    super.init(title: "Naughty")
  }
}

class NiceList: SantaListModel {
  init() {
    super.init(title: "Nice")
  }
}
```

By doing this, both lists can be stored in the environment without clashing. The only thing SwiftUI has to distinguish environment objects is by class. Therefore it is important to have separate classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It seems like a real shortfall in the SwiftUI approach that we have to have to subclass solely to pass different instances of the same model to a common view.  But how does the shared view know which of the models it is receiving - seems we're back to square one?

Comment: @Snips I suppose you've added the object as `NaughtyList()` and `NiceList()` to the environment. In the view which needs the naughty list you will specify the corresponding type : `var santaListModel: NaughtyList` instead of `SantaListModel`. This should do it... based on the type you specify, SwiftUI will get the correct object from the environment.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your suggestion, but the point is that I want a single common shared view implementation to show different instances of the same model.  Another example would be a different instances of a music playlist - seems like a very common requirement.  I have a working solution that passes in a different instance from above but *receives* it was @ EnvironmentObject var aModelInstance: SantaListModel - it apparently matches by the object type based on what's passed on, but seems odd, at best.

Comment: @Snips Ah... sorry, I misunderstood the purpose. If you want to use the same view for the different purposes (=meaning with different data), you shouldn't use the `@EnvironmentObject`. Just use `@Binding` or a regular variable (if you do not need to modify the data in the subview). It's up to the parent view to know whether the purpose is to show the "niceList" or the "naughtyList". E.g. use `SantaListView(santaListModel: niceList)` in `ContentView`.

Comment: Thank you - that actually makes blindingly obvious sense now you say it!  I'll try it in practice and report back.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've tried what you suggest and although it does pass down the model, I'm not getting SwiftUI updates on refreshes, as if the binding is broken (I have to use a custom init as I'm passing in an object with binding).  I will keep investigating.  Thanks again.